# Generating unique reference number

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, primary-key

**Tech Stack**: Java 1.6, JPA (Hibernate 3), Spring 3, Oracle 11g

I am working on a project where one of the requirement is to give back the customers a ‘ReferenceNumber’.

One option is to return the row ID, but for that to work, it must not be sequential. Otherwise, you can guess the next number etc.

I can generate a number in Java and store it in a separate column, but then I’ll have make sure there are no collisions.

There are ways to generate such number in database, but not sure if it will guarantee uniqueness.

*Is there a best practice for such a requirement from the database point of view?*

### **UPDATE 1**

Current I am using the following in Java to generrate the number:

```
    private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public static BigInteger getNew() {
        return new BigInteger(60, random);
    }

    public static BigInteger getNew(int numBits) {
        return new BigInteger(numBits, random);
    }
```

### **UPDATE 2: Requirement**

Allowing sequential number would allow:

1. customer to guess the next number.
2. Find out how many numbers (orders) were there between two number. etc

It is preferable for this reference to be a number, but say a three letter prefix follwed by number is also fine.

Comment: What's wrong with guessing the next number?  What is the seurity requirement?

Comment: @stark has a good point.  You're security shouldn't simply be based on the obfuscation of the reference number.  There should always be an access check against the user and the record.

Comment: Does the `ReferenceNumber` need to be a number?  Could it be an alphanumeric GUID instead?

Comment: I would prefer giving my customers a smaller reference ID than a GUID.

Comment: @RichardClayton - If the goal is to give a human a number that they have to write down and type in, I agree.  If the goal is to give some computer a key that it can use for subsequent calls, a GUID might be reasonable.

Comment: As I updated in the question, the requirement is to have a reference number to customer, preferably in numbers.

Comment: @JustinCave I don't disagree.

Answer (score 2):

If your table has a sequence generated primary key (e.g. the customer_id) then you could reverse the digits and then convert that to an octal representation. Thus it still looks like a decimal number, but it is definitely no longer consecutive and hard to guess any ranges.

The process is even reversable if you can find a way how to deal with trailing zeros in the original value (because they'd become a leading zero in the reversed number and thus will be "dropped" during the conversion).

Answer (score 1):

How about prefixing the number with a customer abbreviation or name abbreviation or something (or 3 letters assigned when the customer is created, checked for uniqueness) and then just have a value stored that you increment sequentially for just that customer? That way they can't tell what the order numbers are in the rest of the system, but they can for themselves, which shouldn't really matter as they know how many orders they have placed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a SHA1 or MD5 Hash of a couple of pertinent fields (say the user's name and the time of record creation, etc.)?  In many respects, if the strategy is well known, your services external to the Database will be able to recreate the reference number without having to query the database.